# how to add Footer inside Linear layout in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <looputill.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loop" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_editUsername"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_s_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:textColor="#0060a4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:text="Sign-In"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my xml i have to add footer  but i unable to add footer in below i am showing screen

desire screen is below [image]

Current screen:

[image]

please tell me how to add footer i tried but its not going to bottom i have applied android aliened bottom property not working 
and also i have to set image view text view bit upper according to desire screen please help .

Comment: try `android:gravity="bottom"`

Comment: have you add footer at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a RelativeLayout with two children. The first is your LinearLayout with  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`, and the second one is the your footer view with attribute  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Create an other layout **fotter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Your Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then include this layout at the end of your main layout like

```
<include layout="@layout/fotter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <looputill.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loop" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_editUsername"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_s_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:textColor="#0060a4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:text="Sign-In"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but there error is given xml linear layout and relative layout top Upper side

Comment: still Error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Put the footer widgets in its own layout and give the layout the following property

```
 android:gravity="center|bottom"
```

then give your TextView or what ever widget you have in the footer the following property

```
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <looputill.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/loop" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_editUsername"
            android:layout_width="226dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_s_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:textColor="#0060a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="236dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:text="Sign-In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_20dp" />

     </LinearLayout>

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="copyright"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `RelativeLayout`. Keep LinearLayout at bottom which contains separator and TextView, or make a separate footer.xml and include it in xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <looputill.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/loop" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_editUsername"
            android:layout_width="226dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_s_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:textColor="#0060a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="236dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:text="Sign-In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <View
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="copyright"
            layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is correct but i want set bit top all thing u can see there less gap between top and imageview

Comment: That is due to gravity center. Use margin @Edge

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your Linear Layout into two parts using layout_weight first part should be of 95% and second part should be 5% keeping Oriention vertical of the main Linear Layout.
and thn you can achieve your result